# Case Q can't be resolved to a variable

Tags: java

Making a program using `case` and the cases are `1`, `2` and `Q`.

Cases `1` and `2` work fine, but Case `Q` which is used to exit the program can't be resolved to a variable (`Q cannot be resolved to a variable`)

Code snippet to follow:

```
        System.out.print("-- MENU -- \n");
        System.out.print("1: Display Journeys \n");
        System.out.print("2: Identify Suitable Journeys \n");
        System.out.print("Q: Quit \n");
        System.out.print("Pick an option: ");

        int option = console.nextInt();

        switch(option) {
            case 1: 
                while(INPUT.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.println(INPUT.nextLine());
                }
               break; 

            case 2:

                    System.out.print("Specify desired location: ");
                    String destination = console.next();

                    System.out.print("Specify Max Time (HH:MM): ");
                    String choice = console.next();

                    // save the index of the colon
                    int colon = choice.indexOf(':');

                    // strip the hours preceding the colon then convert to int
                    int givenHours = Integer.parseInt(choice.substring(0, colon));
                    // strip the mins following the colon then convert to int
                    int givenMins = Integer.parseInt(choice.substring(colon + 1, choice.length()));

                    // calculate the time's total mins
                    int maxMins = (givenHours * 60) + givenMins;

                    System.out.print("Specify maximum changes: ");
                    int maxChange = console.nextInt();

                    // gui spacing
                    System.out.println();

                    // skips the first line which is York
                    INPUT.nextLine();   
                    int mins = INPUT.nextInt();
                    int change = INPUT.nextInt();

                    if ((mins > maxMins) || ((change > maxChange)) && (destination.equals("York") || destination.equals("Alnwick"))) {
                        System.out.format("Time: %02d:%02d, Changes: %d = Unsuitable \n", (mins / 60), (mins % 60), change);
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.format("Time: %02d:%02d, Changes: %d = Suitable \n", (mins / 60), (mins % 60), change);
                    }
                    //Do stuff
                break; 

            case Q:

                System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Maybe you meant to read a `char` and compare it against `'1'`, `'2'`, and `'Q'`?  In any case, you can't just use `Q` without defining it somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you are using the switch expression on int, so 1 and 2 are valid values, but Q without quotes is a variable name, which does not exist in your program.

You probably meant "Q" or 'q', which wont work either- since it's not an int.

If your optional values are 1,2 and Q, you should use a string, and in your cases use "1", "2", and "Q"

This also requires changing:

```
int option = console.nextInt();
```

to:

```
String option = console.nextString();
```

Comment: I'm sure this is what I was looking for, but now I'm having a different error which is: `The method nextString() is undefined for the type scanner`

Answer (score 1):

Early on, you have a line:

```
int option = console.nextInt();
```

This asks to read an int from the console. Since 'Q' cannot be parsed as an int, it will throw an error when typed in.

If you want to keep the `nextInt()`, I would suggest making the options 1, 2, and 9; quit when you see a 9.

---Edit: adding some code---
This code was tested and works.

```
public class SwitchCase {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("-- MENU -- \n");
        System.out.print("1: Display Journeys \n");
        System.out.print("2: Identify Suitable Journeys \n");
        System.out.print("Q: Quit \n");
        System.out.print("Pick an option: ");

        try {
            char c = (char) System.in.read();
            switch (c) {
                case '1':
                    System.out.println("You chose 1.");
                    break;

                case '2':
                    System.out.println("You chose 2.");
                    break;

                case 'Q':
                case 'q':
                    System.out.println("Quitting.");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("You chose something that I couldn't read.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Java 7 or above, it added support for using Strings in switch-case statements. So, you could do `case 'Q':`.

If for some reason you are not on Java 7, read the user input as String instead of int and  convert the user input of 'Q' to an integer in your code internally.